# Are there issues concerning trustworthyness of selinux?

Tags: selinux

Since selinux is/was? developed by the NSA, and with the current noise around privacy etc concerning said agency, should I be concerned about compromised security on my system?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security and should be asked on http://security.stackexchange.com/ 

Comment: @jasonwryan : Are you sure this won't get a better answer here, vis. someone with technical knowledge of the mechanism of selinux and the feasibility of slashmais's thesis?

Comment: @goldilocks the question, as it is currently stated, is about the *trustworthiness* of the technology: that seems to me a question for security.se.

Comment: @jasonwryan: you're right - I was unaware of the IT Secrity site and just had a look; this question was asked and answered there - thanks. (And goldilocks answer reflects the answers there). The question on that site was for some ineffable reason closed ..

Comment: If you want conspiracy theories, what about this one: SELinux came about at a time where other MAC systems (grsecurity, RSBAC) were gaining ground. Properly configuring SELinux policies for a non-embedded system can be really complex and may require a dedicated security administrator. Therefore, NSA's intent in releasing SELinux must have been to prevent the emergence of MAC systems usable by mere mortals. ;-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know very little about selinux as I have not often used it.

However, I do know that the version used by public linux distros is **open source**.  This means that *nothing about its function can be hidden*.

Building in some kind of mechanism to allow the NSA to covertly spy on selinux systems could not be done discretely unless it involved some kind of intentional oversight -- but this could still be found by examining the source code, and anyone can examine the source code.

So there is very very little possibility that the NSA can use selinux against you.  It would not only be virtually impossible to hide, but even more difficult to make look accidental if found.  Since doing something like that would have a very high risk of discovery, no sane person responsible for such a project would take such a risk -- it would almost certainly end up as a very embarrassing waste of time.

Comment: Your certitude is as firm as your optimism. It assumes, without proof, that some *benign* actor has audited the code.

Comment: @jasonwryan I am assuming that, yes.  In fact, I'd assume quite a number of such auditors.  I'm sure if you go look at the bug tracker for selinux you'll find some evidence of them.

Comment: You could copy from the answers and/or add this link: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42383/how-trustworthy-is-selinux

Comment: That is not sufficient evidence to establish "zero" probability of a backdoor; which is what your earlier edit asserted (and I commented on).

Comment: @jasonwryan: Yeah the first version was over the top when I read it -- I was not really thinking about backdoors -- hence "zero" was reduced to "very very little" ;) I agree with the answer from slashmais's link -- there are likely too many people getting paid to check out and work on this stuff for big organizations who depend on it.  You could easily research that.  Consider what happens with every other Java release -- someone finds an accidental backdoor with applets, etc, and oracle has to scamper.  The NSA doing it on purpose is just too wacko, IMO.

Comment: Don't mistake me for a tin foil hat wearer, I just think that, subsequent to the other revelations about the lengths they have gone to, *some* scepticism was warranted; even if it is "very, very little." :)

Comment: @jasonwryan Absolutely -- but to wax philosophical, that's life.  There's nothing worse than death, and you know that's a risk whenever you get into a car.  Most people get in anyway.  Realistically, the NSA probably has a better chance of getting into your system if you *don't* use selinux.  Think about the guy in the tin foil hat being paranoid about seatbelts, lol..."No airbags for me!" etc.